# Cambiar de posicion columnas de una tabla mysql

Tags: mysql

Como puedo cambiar de posicion mis columnas mysql?Las formas que encontre eran haciendo un alter table y añadir la columna del tipo que se desea especificando el lugar donde se quiere insertar pero...si ya tengo una tabla creada con las columnas,se puede cambiar de lugar?

Comment: A qué te refieres con cambiar las columnas de lugar? Si se trata de mostrar las columnas en un orden dado, la recomendación es crear siempre las consultas obteniendo los campos explícitos (SELECT c1, c2, ..., cN from tabla) y no usar SELECT *. E igual, al manipular los resultSets tampoco importa mucho el orden de las columnas... sólo tiene lío cuando haces INSERT INTO tabla VALUES y no indicas los campos destino, lo cual tampoco es buena práctica.

Comment: Intenta dale click derecho en la tabla, te debe de aparecer una opción que se llame Diseño... y después de eso solo arrastras en el orden que tu desees. (Asi funciona en SQL, debe ser casi igual en mySql). Igualmente por codigo puedes ejecutar : Alter Table Modify column "Nombre_Columna" "Tipo(Int,Varchar,ect) After "columna_anterior a la que quieres que este"

Comment: acá muestran una forma de hacer eso. Desconozco si hay un cambio de performance o porque motivo lo harías. Teniendo la tabla creada podrías hacerlo también sin problemas.
<https://www.tutorialspoint.com/easy-way-to-re-order-columns-in-mysql>

Comment: No tiene caso cambiar el orden de las columnas puesto a que solo es la vista, cuando lo llames desde tu código lo acomodas como quieras, no te estreses por eso, de hecho, se podría decir que en MYSQL no tiene un orden especifico, solo se muestran así para que se entienda.
Si comentas exactamente por que los quieres cambiar o que es o que quieres hacer podríamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Creo que deberias aclarar exactamente qué es lo que pretendes lograr, porque como te han dicho, no parece ser tan necesario cambiar la posición de las columnas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para responder tu pregunta, puedes valerte de la sentencia `alter table`/`modify column`, que permite especificar la nueva posición de la columna con la cláusula `after`.

Supongamos que tenemos una tabla así:

```
create table MiTabla (
  Columna1 int
, Columna2 int
, Columna4 int
, Columna3 int
);
```

Y queremos verla *en orden*, podemos lanzar la instrucción:

```
alter table MiTabla modify column Columna3 int after Columna2
```

Si luego hacemos

```
select * from MiTabla;
```

Ya nos devolverá los resultados en el orden esperado:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|Columna1|Columna2|Columna3|Columna4|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|1       |2       |3       |4       |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Dicho esto:

### Piénsalo dos veces

En primer lugar, con un lenguaje de consultas como SQL generalmente **no es necesario** que las columnas de una tabla tengan un orden particular a la hora de realizar una consulta sobre una tabla. Esto porque generalmente se hace referencia explícita al nombre de las columnas dentro de las expresiones de la consulta, y en muchos programas se hace referencia a las columnas por su nombre dentro del conjunto de resultados. De esta manera, no hay ninguna ganancia con tener las columnas en cierto orden.

Pero, en cambio, hay MUCHOS casos en los que no se hace referencia a las cosas por su nombre, sino por su posición en cláusulas `insert` y en lenguajes de alto nivel al procesar resultados obtenidos de una consulta SQL. Un cambio como este tiene el potencial de romper el código existente.

Algo tan sencillo como:

```
insert into Tabla (1, 2, 4, 3);
```

Tendrá un significado completamente nuevo después de realizar una modificación en el orden de las columnas.

Dejé un [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e63773/1/0) con un ejemplo.